# A question about the sound of corona discharge

Tags: transmission-line, power-engineering, harmonics, partial-discharge, corona

In my collage, We were doing an experiment of the air's Breakdown voltage . At the end of the experiment we were listening to the sound of corona (electric partial discharge). The power supply has the ability to vary voltage. The more the **voltage increases**, The **higher the tone** of the sound.

As you can hear in this video: https://youtu.be/KVANbkI8AmM?t=8m23s (At 8:23)

I know that the fundamental "hum" frequency will be twice the electrical frequency due to [Magnetostriction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetostriction) effect. The frequency of the sound  = 100 Hz (in Egypt). So, Why does the tune become higher while rising the voltage?

One more questions, What causes high harmonics in transmission lines? or Why do we hear frequency higher than 100 Hz?

Comment: I'd GUESS that breakdown occurs when the voltage available charges an effective capacitor. The rate which this occurs depends on the driving voltage so a higher voltage produces higher frequencies. But, Imay be wrong :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand the answer to your first question, one needs to start with a voltage low enough that there is no discharge.  This would give you an effective frequency of zero.  As you increase the voltage, it becomes **easier** to ionize the air, so the frequency of the sound (of ionization) increases.

For the second and third questions... higher harmonics are always present, whether we hear them or not, depends on the **sound level** they produce.  Since the power level of the harmonics decreases very rapidly, we may be able to "hear" the  second and even the third harmonic, **only** if the fundamental frequency is loud enough.

Comment: I think this is fundamentally correct. There are several effects occurring simultaneously as the AC voltage increases: 1) the percentage of time during each half cycle of the AC waveform where the voltage/electric field is sufficient for corona discharge increases, and 2) the intensity of the discharges increases. Both serve to increase the overall amplitude of the spectrum, making the higher harmonics more audible.

Answer (score 0):

After watching the video and rereading the original question, I felt my comment did not really answer the question. So here goes:

In the video, the hum that you hear is not corona at all, but the sound of the transformer laminations vibrating, as they typically do in most large transformers. The hum might be caused by magnetostriction in the transformer laminations, but are very likely also caused by the laminations themselves vibrating due to periodic physical forces on them caused by the magnetic field.

To answer your last question of why we hear harmonics higher than 100Hz: the hum that is generated is not a perfect sine wave, even if the AC voltage is a perfect sine (and it often isn't). This is because the vibration of transformer laminations is a non-linear response to the AC current (imagine laminations "slapping" against each other). Since the hum sound is not a perfect sinewave, it will contain harmonics at multiples of the fundamental.

Back to the "corona tone" question: As the voltage is increased in the experiment, the short time at which corona becomes audible (before the arc event, which is NOT corona) increases and indeed the corona sounds of higher frequency. The reason for this is as follows:

A corona is really the sum of many individual small ionizing events occurring sequentially in time. Each of the ionizing events sounds similar to the sound of a "mini spark". As the voltage increases, the rate at which the individual ionizing events occurs also increases. What you are hearing as the increase in tone, is the subjective effect of increasing the rate of individual "mini spark sounds".